# Update query is not reflected into database phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Update query is not reflected into database . This is related to PHP and PDO method of connection. The query I have written is ,

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***; charset=utf8','root','****[enter image description here][1]');
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM providers WHERE password = '$oldpass'";
  $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);  
  $statement->execute();  
  $providers = $statement->fetchAll();
  
  if(($providers[0]["password"]=="$oldpass") and ("$pass"=="$cpass")){
    
    $statement = $conn->prepare('update providers set password="$cpass" where password="$oldpass"');  
    $condition=$statement->execute();
    
    echo '<script>alert("Password changed")</script>';
  }
  else{
    echo '<script>alert("Incorrect old password");</script>';
  }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
            $conn = null;
        }
```

EDIT  The message on entering corresponding credentials is Password changed.

Is there anything wrong with the query??
Because it does not show the updated password in database (phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Please note that the way you're building your queries is unsafe. You're open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You're defeating the purpose of preparing by directly inserting the parameters. Since you're already using PDO, it's easy for you to parametrize your queries.

Comment: Are there any errors? If you don't see them, here's a thorough [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/4205384) on debugging db related problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes you've made will only be visible inside the same transactions, and would be implicitly rolled back when you close the connection. In order to persist them in the database, you need to commit them:

```
$conn->commit();
```

Comment: and don't forget the sql injection problem, of that code

Comment: Connection failed: There is no active transaction
I am getting this error